# EntityFramework: Add row function with row values as parameters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, insert

I have recently used EntityFramework to replace the use of DataSet. There's one function in the dataset that is missing in EntityFramework.

With dataset I have the AddRow method out-of-the-box available:

```
this.DataSet.CustomerDataTable.AddCustomerRow(int cId, int Name, int Telephone, ...)
```

This function is auto-generated, with each column from the table mapped to a parameter. It is very useful 'coz I won't forget any column. But with EntityFramework, this is what I can do:

```
Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
newCustomer.Name = "John";
newCustomer.Telephone = "04xxxxxxxx";
...
context.Customers.Add(newCustomer );
```

It is easy to forget to assigne value to one of the fields if not for the parameterized AddRow method. As I can't find the auto-generated AddEntity function I have to write my own. I was told this function is generated with EntityFramework 4. I'm using 6.1.1 and can't find it.

Could you please tell me how to find this method or achieve similar result without having to write a method by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the model binding of [**Asp.net MVC Framework**](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/)

Quote from [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679587(v=vs.113).aspx)

> **DbSet.Add Method**
>
> Adds the given entity to the context underlying the set in the Added state such that it will be inserted into the database when SaveChanges is called.

By the way, your question is not very clear, in a common MVC scenario, for example, the mapping of your model is done by [**Model Binder**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710776/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-An-Absol)

So, if you have to add a News to your DbSet

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Title,Body,SubTitle")]News model){
  if (ModelState.IsValid){
    ApplicationDbContext.News.Add(model);
    ApplicationDbContext.News.SaveChanges();

  }
}
```

The hard work of binding is done completely by Model Binder

Comment: Sorry that I haven't mentioned that I'm not using a common MVC. I wrote all the code from scratch. Since the DataSet/DataTable model provides the parameterized AddRow method I thought EntityFramework would, too. So the binding have to be done with hands by myself.

Comment: @LionetChen are you in a web-form scenario? o windows forms?

Comment: In a WCF service. I was trying to convert DTOs that are received from WCF calls to EF entities so that I can save them in my database.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion. I'll check it out. I've used a similar library called Omu.ValueInjecter however it is based on the name of the class property. So I have to carefully examine the name and handle the not matching ones. Still an amount of human labour *_*